# Having 500 Internal server error on any error on amazon hosting

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, kohana-3

I am working on amazon hosting using Kohana 3.x , PHP,  and when there comes an error , it instead of showing error , it gives 500 internal server error. Due to which I have to debug my code on localhost but many times error come online only because many things can only be tested online then in that case I have to test it by commenting some part of code or line by line. So is there a way that instead of 500 internal server error it gives me actual PHP error or Kohana error that would be more helpful.

thanks in advance for your time guys.

Comment: Look at Apache's error log. It'll have details about the 500. Always check the logs first, rather than blindly poking around trying to disable code - the error could be occurring before any of your code even begins to execute.

Comment: You try with a "try - catch" ?

Comment: I understand that this is not htaccess error or other apache error. It some time cause because of some errors. Some time when I call some class that don't exist or if it calls some class that exist in a file that don't have proper read/execute permissions. But it don't tell error but just give 500 internal server error.

Comment: @Marc: It is actually giving 500 internal server error on PHP code and it is not apache error that is due to other reasons on other servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all never show PHP errors on a production website!
2. Implement your own HTTP error pages - http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages
3. Setup `bootstrap.php` for production:
   `Kohana::$environment = Kohana::PRODUCTION;`
   `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_STRICT);`
4. Kohana comes up with built in error logging feature. Every HTTP error (404, 403, 500 etc) is automatically saved in `application/logs/month/day.php` file. Open this file and check what was the reason for error.

Comment: If you are going to use Kohana's internal logger with this kind of error, be sure to set write_on_add to TRUE or you will never see any logs:
`Kohana::$log->attach(new Log_File(APPPATH.'logs'), Log::DEBUG, 0);`
`Log::$write_on_add = TRUE;`

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced that in some cases my server will throw a 500 error (even with small stupid errors) if i dont apply these.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Try applying these in the start of your code.

Comment: hmm, I think I need to have a look at it, I know this but didn't think that 500 internal server error is because of this

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .htaccess file? It use to cause 500 internal server errors. Also check your server error logs

Comment: Currently not but I understand that this is not htaccess error. It some time cause because of some errors. Some time when I call some class that don't exist or if it calls some class that exist in a file that don't have proper read/execute permissions. But it don't tell error but just give 500 internal server error.